# Find cell values of subsequent rows when searching for 2 keywords on 2 different columns

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How do i find cell values of subsequent rows when searching for 2 keywords on 2 different columns?

I am trying write a Java program that can search for 2 different search words in an excel sheet.

The keywords are always the same, but where they are in the sheet are not always the same row or column depending on the excel file. The search words are however on the same row, just different columns. I have it taking an input from the user to point to different .xls files each time it runs. I need it to list all of the strings in each cell in subsequent rows. As an example, string in column and row 3,5 is varA and cell 7,5 is varB. I need all of the string values in 3,6 3,7 3,8 etc and the corresponding cells in 7,6 7,7 7,8 etc.

I have used the Apache POI and can successfully find the first search word, don't know how to the second search then the values in the subsequent rows into an a array I can access later.

Comment: Unable to understand. Please give a clear example.

Comment: Are you having trouble with a basic algorithm to see if a row contains your two words, or with the Apache POI code to read the cells ready to check the strings?